# Non consistent git rev-list count

Tags: git

I am working on a zsh custom prompt and I am trying to show how many commits ahead and behind remote my branch is. For that I use the following command

```
git rev-list --left-right --count main...origin/main
```

Which returns `a     b` where a are the commits local is ahead of remote, and b are the commits remote is ahead of local.

I have found an inconsistency I cannot properly understand. Reproduction code below

```
git clone https://github.com/numpy/numpy
cd numpy
git rev-list --left-right --count main...origin/main
#  0     0  # As expected

git reset --hard HEAD~10
git rev-list --left-right --count main...origin/main
#  0     31  # Whaaaaaaat?
```

Can somebody help me understand what am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Merges, merges everywhere…

Comment: hehe, that's a good point, however when I run the command as follows `git rev-list --left-right --count --no-merges main...origin/main`, I still get 21! It's weird

Comment: `git reset --hard` removed merge commit(s) so `git rev-list --no-merges` doesn't help.

Comment: @ivallesp phd is right, what you don't count here is that merge commits don't merely count as one, but also make *other* commits reachable (therefore counted in your 31 here).

Comment: Ok I see, thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [phd noted in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66843244/non-consistent-git-rev-list-count#comment118157113_66843244), removing one *merge commit* from reachability by some branch name will generally remove multiple  commits from reachability.  Given that the numpy repository has a lot of merges on its main branch, the result you saw was unsurprising.

Here is an illustration (not meant to be specific to the numpy repository) where removing one merge commit removes four commits from reachability:

```
...--G--H------L--M   <-- main (HEAD), origin/main
         \       /
          I--J--K   <-- feature
```

Branch `feature` was just merged to branch `main` (and then pushed), so commits `M`, `L`-and-`K`, `J`, `I`, `H`, `G`, and so on are all reachable, working backwards, from commit `M` to which `main` points.

Making `main` point directly to `L`, as we'd get with a `git reset --hard HEAD~1`, removes commit `M` from `main`, but also removes commits `I-J-K`.  So after this reset you'll be "zero ahead" and "four behind" `origin/main`.